# kivy error NameError: global name 'app' is not defined

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, kivy

I wanted to make an App, with two languages(German and English) and settings, so I can switch between the languages.
As the languages class is part of the App, I need to acsess it using app.Lanuage, but I got the error message above.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.settings import SettingsWithSidebar

from setjson import *

Builder.load_string('''
<Interface>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Button:
        text: app.Lanuage.first_caption
        font_size: 150
        on_release: app.open_settings()
''')

class Interface(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Interface, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.test = app.Lanuage.all_button

class SettingsApp(App):
    def build(self):
        config = SettingsApp.get_running_app().config
        language = config.getdefault("example", "optionsexample", "English").lower()

        if language == 'english':
            from lang_engl import Lang
        if language == 'deutsch':
            from lang_deutsch import Lang
        self.Lanuage = Lang()

        self.settings_cls = SettingsWithSidebar
        self.use_kivy_settings = False
        setting = self.config.get('example', 'boolexample')
        return Interface()

    def build_config(self, config):
        config.setdefaults('example', {
            'optionsexample': 'English',
            'stringexample': 'some_string',
            'pathexample': '/some/path'})

    def build_settings(self, settings):
        settings.add_json_panel('Panel Name',
                self.config,
                data=settings_json)

    def on_config_change(self, config, section, key, value):
        print 'value: ' + str(value)


SettingsApp().run()
```

Comment: you only have `App` in the scope, so either you mean `App.Language` or you mean the `kivy.app` module then it would be either `kivy.app.Language` or `from kivy import app; app.Language`. Actually I have neither in my kivy package. Are you sure kivy has a Language class/module?

Comment: no, i created the language class on my own, and added an instance of it to it to the App. And also, it worked perfectly fine in kivy language, but not in python

Comment: Ah, you want a reference to the current app. You can get that via `App.get_running_app()` [documentation](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.get_running_app).

Comment: There is no running App when the Interface is instantiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

Builder.load_string('''
<MyBtn>:
    text: str(self)+self.a.test
<Test>:
    Button:
        text: str(self)+app.test
    MyBtn:
''')


class Test(BoxLayout):
    pass


class MyBtn(Button):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(MyBtn, self).__init__(**kw)
        self.a = App.get_running_app()


class My(App):
    test = '\nHi!'

    def build(self):
        return Test()
My().run()
```

- use `app` keyword to get app in `kv`
- use `App.get_running_app()` if you want to use app in python
- use `self.<object>` inside `App` class(inside `build(self)`)

Other than that, I don't see any other issues you could encounter if you actually access the `App` in your code.

Comment: why does App.get_running_app() returns None

Comment: @GilgameschvonUruk Do you mean in `App` class?

Comment: @GilgameschvonUruk I'm not really sure why it doesn't work for the class that's used in build as `return CLASS()`, but I think the App is available to the other classes _after_ it's completely instantiated, which would mean that when you return the class in build() method, the App class has still some business to do until it's available to the "outer world" and you call your class before the business is done  therefore App.get_running_app() == None in thar moment.